# Export all custom views of the Event Log

Tags: powershell, events

We're moving servers from 2012 to 2016. We have one server that has lots of `Custom Views` in the `Windows Event Log` that we don't want to lose. This can be easily exported one by one by right clicking  and selecting `Export Custom View`. The goal however is to import these all on the new server.

[image]

I can't seem to find an article explaining how this is done with `Powershell`. Creating `events` and `log names/sources` is not a problem but the `Views` is something else

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.verboon.info/2011/12/how-to-automate-the-creation-of-windows-eventlog-custom-views-2/) can be of help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all stored in `%ProgramData%`:

```
Copy-Item -Path "$env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Event Viewer\Views\*" -Recurse -Destination C:\path\to\export\views\to\
```